# how to set the file path in netbeans within the same build directory?

Tags: java, file, netbeans, path, stream

I want to set the path for my file that i'm going to read without having to specify the root directories or the whole path.
like this : `File file = new File("Text01.txt");` 
or `Path file = Paths.get("Accounts.txt");`
instead of : `Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\B_HITMAN\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\BankAccountGUI\\src\\bankaccountgui\\Accounts.txt");`
I even tried to put the file inside the build directory of netbeans, but it didn't work either. it show's this message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Text01.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at assignment01.Assignment01.main(Assignment01.java:19)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your file in the `BankAccountGUI` directory(project's root directory). And then try to access the file like this:-

```
File file = new File("Text01.txt");
```

**Note:-** Your file should be at the same level as the `src` folder.

Comment: I put it in the root directory, but it didn't work. What do u mean at the same level ?

Comment: In the root, you file should be present and even the `src` folder should be present in that path only. It'll work then.

Comment: The file and the src are present and some other files and folder too like the build folder.